# spark strange java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark

I encountered a strange NPE problem in spark these days.

Below is the piece of my code and the related exception.

[image]

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.iflytek.gnome.data.spark.main.SessionModelGeneratorV3$$anonfun$11.apply(SessionModelGeneratorV3.scala:231)
at com.iflytek.gnome.data.spark.main.SessionModelGeneratorV3$$anonfun$11.apply(SessionModelGeneratorV3.scala:231)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:464)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We can see that NPE happens in line 231, but I've filtered `null` values in line 223. Code in line 231 should not throw NPE.

And the NPE just happens accidently. Most times, I just resubmit the job, and all going well.

How does this NPE happen?

---

Added 2021-12-28
The problem happens both in spark2.3.4 and spark2.4.4.

It seems to be related to that `persist`.
I removed `presist` from the code, and the problem never appears again.